# Android - map with 3 buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-button

I am trying to display map in Android for the first time.
Now **`I want to display 3 buttons on the map, and when I clicked on a particular button, that button's click event should be raised.`** The map should be in full-screen and buttons are at the below side.

I don't know how I do this? When we want to display map using a MapView we have to extends the MapActivity class. So please suggest some ideas, examples or reference sites.

Edited:

I have displayed map using the following Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="my generated api key"
        />

    <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is what you need. Though... first make the map appear alone. It seems you haven't done that part. Once you have the map working, it's pretty easy to do the buttons stuff.

Comment: @Cristian checkout i have given the layout coding which i used to display map ..now what i have to do ? thanx for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Praveen's answer is fine. Just keep in mind that one of the greatest avantages of `RelativeLayout` is that you can avoid unnecessary nesting. The more simple your layout, the easier to maintain it is. This is equivalent to Praveen's answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="your_id" />
    <Button android:layout_below="@+id/mapview"
        android:text="@+id/Button03"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button android:layout_below="@+id/mapview"
        android:text="@+id/Button02"
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button03"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: By doing this the Google logo at the bottom of the map might not be showing which does not comply with the terms and conditions of Google. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

the code layout that you need is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="your_id" />


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:layout_below="@+id/mapview" android:text="@+id/Button03"
            android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_below="@+id/mapview" android:text="@+id/Button02"
            android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button03" android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Error in your layout code -> Button01 and Button03 having the same "id"

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: Sorry for that. but the layout design achieve what do you want. and Cristion write a most simplified code. it should works. ;)

Comment: @Paresh thats gr8 and thanx for such support...i cant upvote more than once otherwise sure do it