# google map mixed with buttons, menu

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google maps in my app. and it is somehow always should be there visible in screen. Is it possible to have some buttons, menu,.. beside it on screen? so not the whole screen is the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display button at map one way to do as in this post its working i checked it

[Android - map with 3 buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544875/android-map-with-3-buttons)